# Sometimes cURL unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, curl

I use the curl library for https access. Set the CURLOPT_CAINFO parameter to specify the certificate file. Sometimes normal communication can be achieved,but sometimes cURL raises an error message [SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)]

Here are some of the parameters I set:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_DATA, caFileName);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, caFileName);
```

Thank you for your browsing and advice.

Comment: What do you mean with "sometimes"? Same URL works sometimes and sometimes throws an error? Or different URL and domains? In the latter case your CA likely does not contain the relevant CA for the sites.

Comment: Yes, same url.

Before each file upload, I would apply for the url address, and when the first perform produced an error, I would perform again.

I set the CURLOPT_VERBOSE parameter to 1L and performed 20 file upload tests. The log shows that sometimes it says "SSL certificate verify ok" and sometimes it says "unable to get local issuer certificate".

By the way, there are multiple physical servers on the server side.

Comment: *"there are multiple physical servers on the server side."* - in this case some of these servers are setup in a different way, i.e. either different certificates or missing intermediate certificates. And you get this error with some servers but not with others.

Comment: But with the same URL and the same certificate, sometimes the first execution fails and the second succeeds. Would the case of multiple physical servers lead to such a state?

Comment: *"Would the case of multiple physical servers lead to such a state?"* - it is possible that for each new connection a new DNS lookup is done. If the server farm is balancing load by changing the returned IP address in DNS (or the order of multiple IP) then multiple TCP connections result in accessing multiple servers - which can cause the effect you see if some servers are not properly set up.

Comment: Got it. Thanks  (*￣︶￣)